# Looking for logistic function that passes through the origin and is asymptotic to y = k

Tags: analysis, functions

I need to find a function with the following properties:

For all non-negative x,

1. F(0) = 0
2. lim x=> inf, F(x)=> k
3. F'(0) = 1
4. F"(x) < 0

I believe that the solution will take the form of a logistics function, but its been decades since I finished my math studies.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

I think $F(x)=\arctan x$ will do fine.

$F(0) = \arctan 0 = 0$

$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to +\infty} F(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}$

$F'(0) = \left.\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right|_{x=0} = 1$

$F''(x)=\left(\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right)'= -\frac{2x}{(1+x^2)^2}< 0, \quad x>0 $

[image]