# Looking for logistic-type function that asymptotes to zero and unity at the origin and some positive value, respectively

Tags: probability, analysis, statistics

I am looking for a function whose shape is similar to the logistic function but which approaches $0$ at the origin and $1$ at some location $2c$. The purpose of this function is to be a statistical link function that transforms a bounded variable to a probability. Normally, one uses the logistic link function, which takes values from $(-\infty,\infty)$ to $[0,1]$.

Therefore, I am looking for a function $f$ such that

1. $\underset{x \rightarrow 0}{\lim} f (x) = 0$
2. $\underset{x \rightarrow 2c}{\lim} f (x) = 1$

Further, we should have antisymmetry about the mid point so that for some small $\epsilon>0$,

3. $f(c+ \epsilon ) = 1 - f(c-\epsilon)$.

Further, I am looking for strict convexity and concavity on either side of $c$, just like a sigmoid after it was pointed out to me that I could use a straight line.

4. We have $f(c+\epsilon)$ is strictly concave and $f(c-\epsilon)$ is strictly convex.

This latter requirement is important because the changing at the midpoint has to be 'rapid.' If it is a 'flat' then, $x$ values around the midpoint have little influence over the probability and the underlying variable that varies on $[0,2c]$ is incentivised to hit the 'corners' to attain extreme probabilities.

I believe that the aforementioned requirements rule out shifting the logistic function to the interval $[0,\infty]$ because no good concept of a midpoint $c$ exists where $f(c)= \frac{1}{2}$.

I have looked around and found the generalised logistic function as well as a this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4049400/looking-for-logistic-function-that-passes-through-the-origin-and-is-asymptotic-t). But the objective there is quite different as negative infinity as part of the domain is not ruled out.

I want to use this function as a "link function" for a statistical application where an energy measurement shifts probabilities. But energies vary between $0$ and a maximal amount, not between negative and positive infinity.

I would be much grateful for your help.

Comment: I think the straight line through $(0,0)$ and $(2c,1)$ has all those properties.

Comment: @GerryMyerson well played! Does there exist a function however, that also possesses an inflection point and is strictly convex and concave on either side of c? I shall update the question accordingly.

Comment: You've had a couple of answers. You have the option of "accepting" one of them, by clicking in the check mark next to it. If neither answer is what you want, you can edit your question to clarify what's still to be done.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I am having a careful look and shall get back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\bigg(1-\cos\bigg(\frac{\pi x}{2c}\bigg)\bigg), \ x \in [0,2c]$$

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x)={1\over2}\left(\biggl({x\over c}-1\biggr)^3+1\right)$$

This was found as follows:

Start with $f(x)=x^3$. It's an odd function, so it has the kind of symmetry we're looking for, but with respect to $x=0$ instead of $x=c$. Also, $f(c)-f(-c)=2c^3$, so divide by $2c^3$ to get

$f(x)={x^3\over2c^3}$. Now we have $f(c)-f(-c)=1$, but $f(c)=1/2$ and $f(-c)=-1/2$. So add $1/2$ to get

$f(x)={x^3\over2c^3}+{1\over2}$. Now $f(c)=1$ and $f(-c)=0$, but we want these values at $x=2c$ and $x=0$, so shift everything to the right by $c$, leaving us with

$f(x)={(x-c)^3\over2c^3}+{1\over2}$, and we're done.

Comment: Thank you so much for suggesting this answer. Unfortunately, f(c+e) is convex, exactly the other way round. I want to use this as a link function, so the change in the middle (around c) has to be rapid otherwise the optimiser picks extreme values.

Comment: OK. It can still probably be done with a cubic.

Comment: I think $f(x)=((x^2)/(4c^2))(3-(x/c))$ works.